# Show / Hide form with File field with jQuery in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to have a Hidden form in SB Bootstrap 2. I am using jQuery code from this site: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

I am using "Varying modal content based on trigger button" code.
It works great, but when I add a  field, javascript is trowing an error and the form will not Show. Any suggestions on how to show/hide a form with jQuery with type="file" in it?
Thank you.

Comment: Did you happen to copy the code straight from their site? If so, the JavaScript has a line to set the value of `.modal-body input`, but you can only set a filename programmatically to an empty string (you can't set it to the recipient). If this is your trouble, just change that line to something like: `modal.find('.modal-body input:not([type=file])').val(recipient)` -https://jsfiddle.net/syy4r144/

Comment: could you add code you have so far?

Comment: Yes I did copy the code directly from the site. I will try your suggestion. Thank you

Comment: @Guntar Let me know if it doesn't work. Tag me though, so I know to come back (just use the `@` sign, and start typing `mark`, then select me).